# Reindex and Interpolate on complex Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2016-12-31','2018-12-31','2017-06-30','2019-06-30',],'Business':['FRC','FICC','FRC','FICC']\
              ,'Amount':[10,100,20,200]})
df
   Amount Business        Date
0      10      FRC  2016-12-31
1     100     FICC  2018-12-31
2      20      FRC  2017-06-30
3     200     FICC  2019-06-30
```

I wanted to use the re-index and interpolate functions to get an output such as :

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2016-12-31','2018-12-31','2017-06-30','2019-06-30','2017-03-31','2019-03-31'],'Business':['FRC','FICC','FRC','FICC','FRC','FICC']\
              ,'Amount':[10,100,20,200,15,150]})
df
   Amount Business        Date
0      10      FRC  2016-12-31
1     100     FICC  2018-12-31
2      20      FRC  2017-06-30
3     200     FICC  2019-06-30
4      15      FRC  2017-03-31
5     150     FICC  2019-03-31
```

In essence, I need to divide the dataframe into two clusters and use the interpolate function on each cluster separately.So, the FRC cluster will have an interpolation of 15 and the FICC cluster an interpolation of 150

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Try doing a groupby on whatever column defines your "clusters" (Business?), then pick your x and y values (date and amount respectively?), generate the new x's that you want to interpolate over, and use `numpy.interp` to produce the corresponding interpolated y values for each "cluser". Once you're done, convert the result back into a DataFrame. Are you basically just asking for code to do that?

Comment: @scnerd I was struggling to get a solution and tried to reindex using both business and Date but did not get the right answer. I'll try to build some code around your suggestion and post the results if successful. The code would have been an easier option. However, am happy to spend some time trying to figure it out myself. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the data first and then use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) to set the values.

```
out = pd.DataFrame()
businesses = df.groupby('Business')
for idx, business in businesses:
    name = business.Business.unique()[0]
    temp = business.set_index('Date').resample('3M').interpolate()
    temp.Business = name
    out = out.append(temp)
out = out.reset_index(drop=True)
out
        Date  Amount Business
0 2018-12-31   100.0     FICC
1 2019-03-31   150.0     FICC
2 2019-06-30   200.0     FICC
3 2016-12-31    10.0      FRC
4 2017-03-31    15.0      FRC
5 2017-06-30    20.0      FRC
```

I interpreted a resample rate of 3 months based on your example, but if your real data is slightly different you could put in some logic to calculate the time interval of interest (days, months, years, ...) and use that as your resampling period.

Comment: thanks. One quick question. Is group some kind of class /function ? thanks.

Comment: still get an error: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: Yea I assumed your `Date` field was formatted as a datetime. You can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert it and this wouldn't be a problem.